# Iran visa rejection - should I bother reapplying?

Tags: visas, visa-refusals, iran

I just found out that my sister got her Iran visa approved while mine was rejected, even though we are twins and had the same information in our application. We used the services of Key2Persia, and they said that the MFA didn't give a reason for my rejection. We were planing to fly to Iran in a month, so my question is, should I try applying with an other agency or would I be just wasting my money because I got flagged for some reason and won't get approved anyway?

By the way, I'm from Colombia and the only controversial countries I have traveled to are Russia and the USA, which I didn't have to disclose in the visa application.

Comment: Did you try to apply directly to the diplomatic office of Iran in your country?

Comment: I call them and they said I had to get the visa code with an agency in Iran, so we did. I contacted them embassy today and they just said they don't do anything related to the visa

Comment: @MarkMayo we applied at the same time using the same company

Comment: Unfortunately we're unable to predict whether or not you'll be rejected.

Answer (score -1):

That's quite weird but still, you must reapply. Try to ask help from the Iranian embassy or hire a third party company(if any) that will help you process your visa.

Comment: I used a tour company in Iran call key2persia. I call the embassy in Colombia and they said they couldn't do anything because they have nothing to do with the visa. And i reapply and got rejected again. Thanks for the comment but i wont waist more money i'll travel somewhere else

Comment: Just reapplying is futile. Unless the application process is irrational, applying again with the same information will surely result in the same rejection.